# Asp.Net 2 Membership.ValidateUser only working with Case Insenstive username

Tags: sql, asp.net, forms-authentication

Asp.Net 2.0 Membership, MemberShip.ValidateUser not working with case sensitive username. I tried setting loweredusername column in aspnet_users to case sensitive. Something like  this

```
ALTER table aspnet_Users alter COLUMN LoweredUserName NVARCHAR(256)
COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CS_AS NOT NULL
```

but is also didn't work.

Any idea on how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

I just was going in the wrong direction. Issue was with Membership.ValidateUser in Asp.Net membership method targets to store procedure **[aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat]**. In this stored proecedure we need to change

```
  Lower(@username) = m.LoweredUserName to @username = m.username.
```